# Do I need to mock the required module in Jest testing

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I had a `mixin/Utils.js` to test, where `underscore` is required and used in the module. Something like:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var Utils = {

   foo: function(arrayOfArray) {
    return _.sortBy(arrayOfArray, function(array) {

      return -1 * array[1].length;

    }) || {};


   }

};
module.exports = Utils;
```

When I tried to use Jest to test it, I made something like below. But the test failed. I had a feeling that was because I didn't mock the `underscore`. But how should I mock that? And in general if the module has dependencies like `underscore`, how should I set the mock correctly and test the module?

```
 var __path__ = "PATH_TO/mixins/Utils.js";


 jest.dontMock(__path__);



 describe("Test for mixins/Utils.js", function() {

    var Utils;

    beforeEach(function() {
    Utils = require(__path__);
});

   describe("countInversion", function() {

    it('Passing in [[0, [1,2]], [1, [1,2,3]]] and should get [[1, [1,2,3]]],[0, [1,2]] ', function()        {
        var testInput = [[0, [1,2]], [1, [1,2,3]]];
        var expectedOutput = [[1, [1,2,3]]],[0, [1,2]]; 
        expect(Utils.FOO(testInput)).toEqual(expectedOutput);
    }); 
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest mocks everything by default so you you actually do *not* want to mock underscore if your unit test depends on functionality in underscore. You should either add `jest.dontMock('underscore')` to your test, or include it in the `unmockedModulePathPatterns` property of your jest config to get the output you expect.

### Edit

As @pgericson has noted in the comments, Jest [no longer automocks as of jest 15](https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html#disabled-automocking). [Jasmine spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) can be used in lieu of automocks.

Comment: As of jest version 15.0.0 it does not automock any modules. [announcement of removal](https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html#disabled-automocking)